# Facebook login accidentally logs into someone else's account

Tags: node.js, mongodb, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using facebook SDK for social login, it works well most of the time, but sometimes when a user tries to login with Facebook they accidentally logs into someone else's account.

I am using facebookId as unique Id in my DB, and if an existing user logs in again, through this facebookId i validate his/her account.

```
/* Find user by Fb id */
accountModel.findOne({ facebookId: req.body.fbId }, function (err,resultUserByFb) {
 if(err){
 }
 else {
  sendLoginResponse()
 }
});
```

If the facebookId is not present in the DB, we register that user into the system.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: if facebookId is supposed to be unique, why are we having users with duplicate id

Comment: What do you mean with duplicate IDs?

Comment: That sounds like a really *bad* bug but it's not obvious here what the problem could be.

Comment: Make sure you treat Facebook ids as strings, always and everywhere, along the whole chain. Treating them as integers can easily lead to problems, with significant digits getting cut/altered due to precision issues.

Comment: @KetanSaresa Can you do a `console.log(req.body.fbId, typeof req.body.fbId)`?  As CBroe says, Facebook IDs are strings, not integers.  If you treat them as integers, higher-numbered IDs overflow in JavaScript.  These are hard bugs to catch as it might only affect odd or even-numbered IDs, or your own ID might be low enough to not overflow.

Comment: I do not treat them as integers, it's a string only. I have added the console.logs to track the issue, but so far it looks good, it's just one of the time, when user logs into another user's account..